# ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function / ionic3 flurry-analytics plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-analytics, flurry-analytics

I am getting this error when I tried to log an event using Flurry plugin:
https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics

(I was getting the same error when I used firebase-analytics plugin and I was unable to resolve that as well: 
https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics)

The code I used in my `insights.ts(one of my component)` in `ionViewWillEnter()` :

```js
const options: FlurryAnalyticsOptions = {
      appKey: 'my key', // REQUIRED
      userId: 'prash1234',
      reportSessionsOnClose: true,
      enableLogging: true
    }

let fa: FlurryAnalyticsObject = this.flurry.create(options);

    let ovenParams = {
      temp: 350,
      mode: 'convection',
      rackPosition: 'center'
    }

    fa.logEvent('set oven', ovenParams)
      .then(() => { console.log('something')})
      .catch((e) => console.log('error'));
```

Error I get when I run the app:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at FlurryAnalyticsObject.logEvent (index.js:26)
    at InsightsPage.webpackJsonp.171.InsightsPage.ionViewWillEnter (insights.ts:60)
    at ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:566)
    at ViewController._willEnter (view-controller.js:454)
    at Tab.NavControllerBase._willEnter (nav-controller-base.js:966)
    at nav-controller-base.js:828
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:4149)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
```

My package json:

```
{
  "name": "myFlurryApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/flurry-analytics": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.91",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics": "1.4.6",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "1.8.6",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "datepicker-ionic2": "^2.6.2",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.6",
    "ion2-calendar": "^2.2.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.1",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.8.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "11.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

ionic -v
`4.3.0`

Android
`7.1.4`

Please help me with this.
Thanks :)

Comment: Actually what is your Ionic version ? Because In your question you mention v4 and in tags you are using `ionic3` tag.

Comment: Hi @SudarshanaDayananda, I am using ionic cli-4.3.0, but the project which I made is for ionic 3. That's why I mentioned ionic-3

Comment: And just one more thing, I even tried to change the cli version from ```4.3.0``` to ```3.12.x``` but the problem is same.

Comment: are you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @AbhijitChakra, yes I was able to solve this problem by switching the version of flurry plugin. And then change the version of the service (flurry service) in the android file.  

PS: I won't recommend this plugin though, it causes a big problem when you build your iOS project. If they solved the build problem for iOS last year then you can use it for sure.

Comment: @saberprashant thanks for quick reply ..due to angular breaking changes somethods doesnt work you have to play heat and trail with versons with ios it asked me to install pods then now its working...Do you know what is a good alternative for this..You can post your answer here may be it would help others to get a hint

Answer (score 0):

To solve this:

- Switch the version of the flurry plugin.
- then change the version of the service (flurry service) in the android file. Make it the same as the plugin.

PS: I won't recommend this plugin though, it causes a big problem when you build your iOS project. If they solved the build problem for iOS last year then you can use it for sure.

Edit:
Now with Ionic & capacitor, you can solve this issue.

```js
npm install cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics
npm install @ionic-native/flurry-analytics
ionic cap sync
```